# Windows Azure Language Pack

Tags: iis, azure

does anyone know what language packs are installed by default onto a Windows Azure VM?  I need to know because I need to support multiple languages for the IIS httpErrors custom errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only US English. And TimeZone is UTC. You can localize your custom errors page by yourself. The operating system is just in US English.

Comment: ok thanks.  I'll have to come up with my own way to localizing error pages as IIS doesn't seem to support locales like 'fr-CA', just 'fr-FR' and this won't do.