# Azure .NET language packs

Tags: .net, azure, localization

Are some .NET language packs deployed on Azure, or are we limited to en-US?
This is required to get localized standard error messages.
We are using Azure Cloud Services. We need at least French for now.

This is related to the following question, except that this one is about .NET:
[Windows Azure Language Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311697/)

Comment: Did you manage how to do it ?

Comment: We haven't made any progress on this.

Comment: OK. You can support my ticket for this on Azure suggestions here : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the language pack does not come installed on your Azure Instance you will have to package the installer with you deployment and [create a Startup Task](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/01/utilizing-the-power-of-startup-tasks-in-your-windows-azure-web-role/) to install the language pack when your instance initializes.

This will make your deployments run a bit longer, but it should meet your needs.

Comment: the link provided is dead.

Comment: If you want language packs to be added to Azure Web Apps, please vote for this request : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps